# Help With Data Recovery

Tags: installation, 13.04, windows, data-recovery

I just want to ask whether I can recover data from a windows partition after installing ubuntu over it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to boot from Ubuntu live CD and use Photorec and Diskutils to recover some of the lost data. However since you wrote new data to the partition some files may be lost forever. Remember that you must recover the data on an external hard drive or flash disk.